# Understanding Lemma 2.1, p-19 of Munkres’ Topology 2E.

Tags: functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function-theorem

Lemma 2.1 on page 19 of Munkres’ Topology 2E is stated as follows.

Lemma 2.1

Let $ f:A→B$. If there are functions $ g:B→A $ and $ h:B→A  $ such that $ g(f(a))=a $ for every $ a∈A $ and $ f(h(b))=b $ for every $ b∈B,$ then $ f $ is bijective and $ g=h=f^{-1}.$

My attempt to proof is as follows.

Proof:

Since $ g:B→A $ is a function and $ g(f(a))=a $ for every $ a∈A,
 f(x)=f(y)  ⇒ g(f(x))=g(f(y))  ⇒x=y\;  ∀x∈A $ and $ ∀ y∈A. $

Hence, $ f $ is injective.

Since $ h:B→A $ is a function and $ f(h(b))=b $ for every $ b∈B$, we have
$∀b∈B,∃a∈A $ such that $ h(b)=a $ and $ f(a)=f(h(b))=b. $

Hence $ f $ is surjective.

So, $f $ is bijective and it follows that $g=h=f^{-1}$.∎

I’d like to request you to check the above proof and correct if you don’t mind.
Although there is already a similar question and answers, I'd like to keep mine as a duplicate.

Comment: This is an excellent proof of the bijectivity of $f$!

Comment: Functional Analysis is  an advanced topic and it does not stand for analysis of functions. I have removed that tag.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the duplicate at the moment.